# "Under one year old" versus "Less than one year old"

Tags: grammaticality

Which is correct:

- *Amy has a child under a year old*
- *Amy has a child less than a year old*

Comment: As a native speaker I'd say either is correct, but I'd mark "less than" as more common.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct, though *less than one year old* is more common.

Here is a view of [the popularity of those terms over time](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=under+one+year+old%2Cless+than+one+year+old%2C+under+1+year+old%2C+less+than+1+year+old&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800) (in English language books):

[image]

So it looks like "less than" overtook "under" (in books) around 1930.

In text on the web, "under one" has [378k](https://www.google.com/#q=%22under+one+year+old%22+OR+%22under+1+year+old%22) hits while "less than one" has [38M](https://www.google.com/#q=%22less+than+one+year+old%22+OR+%22less+than+1+year+old%22) (100 times as many).

Fun fact:  this question is already the top hit on Google for the above "less than one" link.

Comment: Wonder what those "under 1" spikes are in World War I (ish) and the early 90s?